# WiFi Repeater Creation

Tags: wireless, command-line

I need to make my pc act as wifi repeater. It is possible in windows using netsh commands or connectify software 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-WiFi-Hotspot-Using-the-Command-Prompt

Is there any such software or command available for ubuntu/linux ?